# How to configure Django to Use mysql

Tags: mysql, django

I'm totally new to django, I've just passed the tutorials, I try to use it with mysql, with setting my backend in settings file and put mysql user and password,
But did not succeed.
What else should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure [DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases) setting in settings.py.

Here's an example configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```